# Getting ActiveDirectory title using Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I have got a project with `Membership`.

I want to aquire the users' titles.

I don't see any suitable property. Is there any I can use?

If not, what provider do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to query Active Directory for properties you need by yourself in controller

Second way is to create your own membership provider.